# Custom pipe to templateUrl

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have created a custom pipe.

```
import { Component, Pipe,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css']
})

@Pipe({
    name:'summary'
})
export class SummaryComponent implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value:string,args?:any) {
   // details
}
```

In my app.component.html. I have

```
 <app-summary></app-summary>
```

And in my summary.component.html, I have

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" >
<br>
{{title}}
```

I want to use the pipe in `{{title}}`. But it seems that the pipe is not applied. What I am missing?

**EDIT:**
I added the pipe code details.

```
import { Component, Pipe,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-summary',
   templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css']
})

@Pipe({
    name:'summary'
})
export class SummaryComponent implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value:string,args?:any) {
       if(!value)
          return null;
          let prep = ['of','the'];
       let splitted = value.split(' '); 

       for(var i=0;i<splitted.length;i++){
           if(i>0 && prep.includes(splitted[i].toLowerCase()))
              splitted[i]=splitted[i].toLowerCase();
           else
           {
            splitted[i]= splitted[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+splitted[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
           }
       }
       return splitted.join(' ');
  }
}
```

Comment: This code sample is a bit wierd: you're implementing something called `SummaryComponent` decorated as a `@Pipe`, but you have no component logic? What exactly are you trying to do here? 20 people will tell you the answer is `{{ title | summary }}` but if your code listing is complete, you may have bigger problems.

Comment: @msanford, I have the implementation.  I didn't write it for just saving space. I added `summary`, but it has error: compiler.es5.js:1689 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'summary' could not be found ("<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" >

Comment: Ok, but is your *pipe module* called `SummaryComponent`?

Comment: Ma Kobi has provided a pipe implementation. It's fine to save space by writing what Ma Kobi did below, but the annotations in your sample are incorrect, which is probably what's causing the error; it's not clear if that's just space-saving or if that's the real code you're trying to run. _Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)._

Comment: @msanford, I added the code details. Please advise me.

Comment: You are using the `@Pipe` Decorator on the Summary Component and implementing the PipeTransform Interface which is very confusing. You need to decorate the actual Component with the `@Component` Decorator and create a extra Pipe class and decorate it with `@Pipe` Decorator. For details check my answer below. And don't forget to provide the Pipe in the Module. Otherwise the pipe could not be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to implement a pipe:

**summary.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name:'summary'
})
export class SummaryPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value:string,args?:any) {
    // details
  }
}
```

**summary.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css']
})
export class SummaryComponent {

}
```

Then you can use the pipe in your view like this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" >
<br>
{{title | summary }}
```

Don't forget to add the `SummaryPipe` in the NgModule in which you want to use it:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SummaryComponent,
    SummaryPipe
  ],
  providers: [...]
})
export class SummaryModule { }
```

Comment: You comment that our answers do not work because the pipe is not properly implemented, but your answer doesn't fix that either. This is literally the same as the first two answers, but more verbose. Your pipe `transform` is still not implemented "correctly", either.

Comment: I have @NgModule in app.module.ts rather than in summary.component.ts. Is it right?

Comment: You must have the `@NgModule` decorator in a module. This can be the app.module.ts or a other child module. On a component you need the `@Component` decorator and on a pipe you need the `@Pipe` decorator. If you want to use it on a child module you need to declare it in the child module.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" >
<br>
{{title}}
```

To this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" >
<br>
{{title | summary}}
```

You have not actually applied the `summary` pipe when rendering `title`.

Comment: Won't help, because the Pipe is not correctly implemented.

Comment: Obviously, but one step to solving this problem is properly using the pipe when rendering your variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell angular that you want to use that pipe like below :

```
{{title | summary}}
```

Comment: This is not an correct answer because the pipe is not correctly implemented.

Comment: @MaKobi probably the op omitted the contents for brevity

Comment: I omitted the pipe code. If I add the pipe summary following the `title`, compiler.es5.js:1689 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'summary' could not be found ("<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" >

Comment: If the content is omitted the code is very confusing because the Component is decorated with `@Pipe` and the `@Component` decorator has no class to decorate.